# wordpress - load a template based on the URI

Tags: templates, urls, routing

I have a number of custom of post types - i.e. `'windows'`, `'doors'`, `'garages'`

and I want to load a custom template (`special.php`) whenever my wordpress site has a url that looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/windows/
www.mysite.com/doors/
www.mysite.com/garages/
```

I don't want to use pages, as it is not appropriate in this case (I have given a scaled down example in the above example)

**How can I achieve this?**

Currently, as no pages exist with those names, I am getting an 404 (index.php)

Comment: hmmm perhaps this would have been better on the Wordpress Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your custom post type windows would map onto /windows/ etc?

You can customise the template for individual custom post types via single-posttype.php in your theme, e.g. single-windows.php single-doors.php and single-garages.php Wordpress will automatically pick these up

You could also use custom page templates, e.g. page-windows.php or custom templates with the right template names.

If the pages are intended to list the post types, then you could try creating post archive templates, e.g.: http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/

Or, you could create a taxonomy for each of said names, and use taxonomy-windows.php

Using all fo the above, one could share the code using something along the lines of:

```
<?php
// example code, may need minor modifications
get_template_part('special',$post->post_type);
```

Allowing you to share the code for all the pages in one file, and giving you child theme support, and the ability to override via files such as special-windows.php

OR, if none of the above suit you, there is a final solution:

http://www.braindonor.net/coding-blog/custom-pages-with-wordpress-plugins/230/

This will let you put a page with whatever you want, wherever you want, without needing any posts or pages of any kind, in a theme independent way.

Answer (score 0):

move all your script in single.php to anthor template called say "narmol.php"

and in the single.php, place a condition like

```
 if(post_type="windows" || "doors" || "garages") include "special.php";
 else include "normal.php";
```

the above code is just an idea(Pseudocode). I assume you know how to implement it. let me know if you dont know.

Comment: Or you could use the single-windows.php single-doors.php and single-garages.php templates?

Comment: @Tom as I understand, if the post type is windows,doors or garages, it will load the same special.php. your solutions can be applied when they want to load different template for each post type

Comment: If Wordpress is loading the template for a post of type 'windows' it will first attempt to load single-windows.php and if that fails it will load single.php

Comment: Your snippet of code is therefore completely unnecessary, and replicates existing wordpress functionality

Comment: afterall wouldnt it be easier to do put <?php get_template_part('special',post_type); in those files? Allowing for sharing of the same code, but with the option of child themes, and overriding?

Comment: if it loads the temaplate as you decribe above. I will give an upvote. and then my code is not useful. I thought that loading method only applied to categories.

Comment: eh you didnt know! I've used the same code myself in the past =p

Answer (score 0):

When you register new post type, there's an argument that will enable the post type archives `has_archive` (check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)). When you enable post type archive, these urls:

```
www.mysite.com/windows/
www.mysite.com/doors/
www.mysite.com/garages/
```

will uses `archive-$post_type.php` as the template file. And if the file `archive-$post_type.php` doesn't exist, it will looks for `archive.php`. (check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display))

So I think a simple solution for you is checking the `$post_type` in `archive.php` file and when it's one of `windows, doors, garages` then we include `special.php`, like this:

```
<?php
// archive.php
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
if (in_array($post_type, array('windows', 'doors', 'garages'))) {
    include 'special.php';
    exit;
}

// default content for other archive type
?>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to set `has_archive` to `true` when you register post type.