# How to use get_post_custom function on the blog page?

Tags: metabox

First, I have a static page for homepage and for blog page too. I created a custom box for pages to setup unique background image for the pages. My idea is working on all page templates, but on blog page something wrong.

**header.php is same on all page**

```
<head>
{...}
<?php $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );  ?>
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-image:url("<?php echo $values['background_image_meta'][0]; ?>"); }
</style>
{...}
</head>
```

Comment: You don't really explain what doesn't work-- "something wrong" is essentially meaningless-- but I expect that you don't have a `$post` variable or it isn't set to what you expect to be. Add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and more detail about the problem.

Comment: It means the value is NULL but on other pages everyting ok. How to set the $post varriable correctly?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: background_image_meta` I turned on the debug, this is the result.

Comment: See if this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91249/how-to-get-the-custom-post-type-from-an-archive-page/91254#91254

Comment: If the page being shown does not have an associated post, where would the post meta/custom fields come from? They cant just eb created out of thin air, they need to come from somewhere. Clearly this is a failure to provide default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that there is no variable `$post` in your `header.php`. That variable might exist in the [**global** scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), but your code operates in a function scope of `load_template()` which was called by `get_header()`.

So you have four options:

1. Import the global variable into your function with the `global` keyword.
       global $post;

   ```
   // make sure everything is set up as a post object
   $post   = get_post( $post );
   $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
   ```
2. Use `get_queried_object_id()` to get the ID, similar to [hepii110’s suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93914/73).

   ```
   $values = get_post_custom( get_queried_object_id() );
   ```
3. Use `get_the_ID()`. This does almost the same as version 1.

   ```
   $values = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
   ```
4. Call `get_post_custom()` without the post ID. It will try to find the correct ID automagically.

   ```
   $values = get_post_custom();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
```

to

```
$values = get_post_custom( get_queried_object()->ID );
```

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: I tested it. I created a static page, and used as a blog page. I tried to get the custom value with the first code `$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );` but it returns an other post id. The `$values = get_post_custom( get_queried_object()->ID );` line returns the correct post id. (The id of the static blog page)